# vhost_net and virtio on KVM

Tags: kvm-switch, virtio

I have read that “vhost_net” offers better performance against “virtio” based on https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linux-kvm.org%2Fwiki%2Fimages%2F5%2F59%2FKvm-forum-2011-performance-improvements-optimizations-D.pdf&ei=sA1nUvz9LsWQlQX_sYHIAw&usg=AFQjCNFmF4aciBkorK9d9dLTghUHnvhxmQ&sig2=9yr66NjOmkLMgu6rNU-mHQ&bvm=bv.55123115,d.dGI

My understanding from googling around is that if “vhost” is set to “ON”, then I am using virtio. Because when I tried to replace “virtio” with “vhost_net” in the XML file, I get an error.

/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm -name rh6_4vm8 -S -machine rhel6.4.0,accel=kvm -m 2048 -smp 2,sockets=2,cores=1,threads=1 -uuid 23a35883-6510-6857-86d2-8106e99efb98 -nographic -nodefconfig -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/rh6_4vm8.monitor,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=readline -rtc base=utc -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb,bus=pci.0,addr=0x1.0x2 -drive file=/home/storage/local/images/rh6_4vm8.qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,format=raw,cache=none -device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3,drive=drive-virtio-disk0,id=virtio-disk0,bootindex=1 -drive if=none,media=cdrom,id=drive-ide0-1-0,readonly=on,format=raw -device ide-drive,bus=ide.1,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-1-0,id=ide0-1-0 -netdev tap,fd=19,id=hostnet0,vhost=on,vhostfd=27 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:13:15:a7,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5 -netdev tap,fd=28,id=hostnet1,vhost=on,vhostfd=29 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet1,id=net1,mac=52:54:00:57:1b:42,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6 -netdev tap,fd=30,id=hostnet2,vhost=on,vhostfd=31 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet2,id=net2,mac=52:54:00:d0:1d:e7,bus=pci.0,addr=0x7 -netdev tap,fd=32,id=hostnet3,vhost=on,vhostfd=33 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet3,id=net3,mac=52:54:00:83:e8:ea,bus=pci.0,addr=0x8 -netdev tap,fd=34,id=hostnet4,vhost=on,vhostfd=35 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet4,id=net4,mac=52:54:00:09:58:67,bus=pci.0,addr=0x9 -netdev tap,fd=36,id=hostnet5,vhost=on,vhostfd=37 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet5,id=net5,mac=52:54:00:86:7b:30,bus=pci.0,addr=0xa -chardev pty,id=charserial0 -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 -device usb-tablet,id=input0 -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4

So my question is. Am I using vhost_net right now? If not, how can I set the vnic’s to vhost_net ?

Answer (score 0):

`vhost=on` in -netdev says that you are using vhost_net.